# Struts 1 login application example error

Tags: struts-1

I am new to Struts and tried to execute Login Form. But it's not getting executed after the default constructor in the ACTION class.

---

LoginForm.java

```
package struts.login.action;

import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LoginForm extends ActionForm {

public LoginForm() {

}

private String username;
private String password;
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}


}
```

LoginAction.java

```
package struts.login.action;

import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;

import org.apache.struts.action.Action;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;

public class LoginAction extends Action {

private final static String SUCCESS = "success";
private final static String FAILURE = "failure";
//private final static String FAILURE = "failure";

public LoginAction() {
    System.out.println("default constructor of Login Action");
}

@Override
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws Exception     {

    LoginForm loginForm = (LoginForm) form;
    if(loginForm.getUsername().equals(loginForm.getPassword())){
        return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS);    
    }
    else{
        return mapping.findForward(FAILURE);    
    }

}
}
```

Login.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tld/struts-html.tld" prefix="html"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="color:red">

</div>
<html:form action="/Login" method="get">
    User Name :<html:text property="username"/><br>
    Password  :<html:password property="password"/>
    <html:submit value="Login Here" />
</html:form>
</body>
</html>
```

success.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Successfully logged in!
</body>
</html>
```

failure.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
login failed please try again!
</body>
</html>
```

struts-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.3//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd">

<struts-config>
<form-beans>
    <form-bean name="loginForm" type="struts.login.action.LoginForm">
    </form-bean>
</form-beans>

<action-mappings>
    <action path="/Login" name="loginForm"             type="struts.login.action.LoginAction" >
    <forward name="success" path="/success.jsp"></forward>
    <forward name="failure" path= "/failure.jsp"></forward>
    </action>


</action-mappings>

</struts-config>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<!-- Standard ActionServlet Configuration -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>config</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>application</param-name>
        <param-value>ApplicationResources</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>3</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>detail</param-name>
        <param-value>3</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Standard ActionServlet Mapping -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Struts Tag Library Descriptors -->
<jsp-config>
<taglib>
    <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/tld/struts-html.tld</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/struts-html.tld</taglib-location>
</taglib>
</jsp-config>
</web-app>
```

I have included struts-html.tld file in WEB-INF/tld folder.
After login with username and password It's not redirected to either success.jsp or failure.jsp page

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, What type of exception you got?

Comment: if you are  new to struts and reading it for your own knowledge than my suggestion is to start with Struts2 not struts as its already have declared it's end of life.

Comment: I am not getting any exception in my console. So I thought it could be related to jars.

Comment: console showing this...last part of console window
it's executing upto the default constructor
Aug 16, 2013 4:00:01 PM org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor init
INFO: Initializing composable request processor for module prefix ''
Aug 16, 2013 4:00:01 PM org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.CreateAction createAction
INFO: Initialize action of type: struts.login.action.LoginAction
default constructor of Login Action

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have passed ServletRequest and ServletResponse in execute method in action class instead of HttpServletRequest and HttpServlet Response..
 Use Like Following

```
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
    HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception     {
}
```

and import these things:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
```

Hope it will work..