# user should not logged in using query string

Tags: struts2

I used login application and it is validating form if userName and password is blank.
Now I am sending userName and password like this
http://localhost:8080/LoginApp/loginAction.action?userName=jagannath&password=123 then also logged in successfully instead of filling login.jsp form page. In this case user should not logged in. How can avoid it using Struts2.

Comment: Show you action and actionForm code? You should use actionForm instead of query strings. Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18269343/struts-1-login-application-example-error

Comment: You need to write a custom interceptor and add it to your custom interceptor stack. In the interceptor, you let only the POST requests pass, and reject the GET requests the way you like more.

Comment: Affectionate query string from the request.

Comment: How can I write  interceptor to POST requests pass, and reject the GET requests ?

Comment: Thank you Andrea... I used this method to check request method                                                                        public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   System.out.println("getMethod==  "+arg0.getMethod());
   methodName= arg0.getMethod();
  }

Comment: You did it in the action class then... it would be better in an interceptor. But at least you've found a way ;)

Comment: @jagannath if you find the way, please answer your question

Comment: Hi Alireza use this method ... setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest arg0)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of validations client side( Html/javascript_ and server side (Java Code).
As of now you are doing client side validation only. You need to server side validation as with url param javascript validation is not called - i.e. validation that you do on input. When param are passed you need to check in java code if they are valid or not.  Sample code below

```
public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport {

    private String userName;
    private String password;

    public String execute() {
        return SUCCESS;
    }


    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void validate() {
        if (getUserName().length() == 0) {
            addFieldError("userName", "UserName.required");
        } else if (!getUserName().equals("Arpit")) {
            addFieldError("userName", "Invalid User");
        }
        if (getPassword().length() == 0) {
            addFieldError("password", getText("password.required"));
        }
    }
}
```

More details [here](http://www.java2blog.com/2012/07/login-page-with-validation-in-struts-2.html)

Comment: Sorry dude but I guess this is not what OP is asking. He never said or implied he is using any client side validation. He is asking how to block GET requests from autheticating the user, and let only the POST requests pass.